# How can I make a conditional statement in Python, and if input is the same twice if will send an error

Tags: python

So I made a groceries list in Python. But, if the user answer the same input such as banana twice, it will check the banana is already in the basket. How can I do this?

```py
fruit = ['Banana', 'Mandarine', 'Apple']
using = input('Which fruit are you going to buy')

if using in fruit:
    print('Good Fruit')
else:
    print('That is not a good fruit!')
```

So, what can I do better?

Comment: Have you tried creating a list which tracks the fruits the user has already inputted?

Comment: Huh! I didn't know about that. Are there any good examples??

Comment: @Pingu Wouldn't be a useful solution if that list is needed later on, unless rephrased to a list of possible choices where the fruits are acquires from, let's say, a dictionary of fruit-price values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list for the fruits that the user has already input (as suggested by B Remmelzwaal). Considering the code that you have already written, you can implement it as:

```
basket = []
fruit = ['Banana', 'Mandarine', 'Apple']

n = 5
for i in range(n):
    
    using = input('Which fruit are you going to buy: ')
    
    if using in fruit:
        print('Good Fruit')
    else:
        print('That is not a good fruit!')
        
    if using not in basket:
        basket.append(using)
    else:
        print('Fruit was already in basket!')

print(basket)
```

Here I have set n (which is the number of times the user will be asked) to 5. Please edit it as desired.

Here is an example of its working:

```
Which fruit are you going to buy: Banana
Good Fruit
Which fruit are you going to buy: Apple
Good Fruit
Which fruit are you going to buy: Banana
Good Fruit
Fruit was already in basket!
Which fruit are you going to buy: Grapes
That is not a good fruit!
Which fruit are you going to buy: Apple
Good Fruit
Fruit was already in basket!
['Banana', 'Apple', 'Grapes']
```

Comment: @JacksonNguyen You should mark this answer as a solution if it answers your question :)